# Can I improve my habitat?

Tags: dragonvale

In *DragonVale* you can acquire a multitude of dragons. Unfortunately, some of their habitats are small; some can only hold 1 dragon (the nerve)!

The problem is, I wasn't aware of this fact. Probably because I can't be bothered to read tutorial hints. So, there I am all excited about buying *another* Earth Dragon, only to realize I would have to buy another habitat to keep him in!

**Can I upgrade my existing habitats to hold more dragons?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, once you unlock the Large habitat of a type, any Small habitat of that type can be upgraded in place. There's only two habitats of each type; a normal and a small. You can see a whole list of [Dragonvale Habitats](http://dragonvale.wikia.com/wiki/Habitats) on the wiki too. Small habitats usually hold 1-2 dragons where large ones generally hold 3-4 dragons.

The upgrade will cost the same price as the large habitat would otherwise and take the same time, but the Small habitat will function normally while you're upgrading. This means your dragons can stay put and still earn money.

In fact sometimes I find it helpful to buy a small habitat first and then upgrade it, as I get the first 1/2 dragon slots quickly and then the habitat is in use while the upgrade prepares for completion.

Answer (score 0):

A small habitat can be bigger with evolving to large habitat.
You can also dragons in a hibernation cave dropping.